# Vertical align in Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: html, email, outlook, vertical-alignment

I have an html newsletter which works in most email carriers but the formatting is messed up in outlook. Here is a snippet of the email as this is the only part that is playing up:

```
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#666f87" style="background: #666f87;">
                                                    <div style="color: #cccccc;">
                                                        <p style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0;"><strong>Social Media:</strong></p>
                                                        <p style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                            <img style="border:0; display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /><span style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0;"><a style="color: #cccccc;" href="#" title="Facebook" >Become a fan on Facebook</a></span>    
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                            <img style="border:0; display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /><span style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0;"><a style="color: #cccccc;" href="#" title="Twitter" >Follow us on Twitter</a></span>    
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px;">
                                                            <img style="border:0; display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" src="youtube.png" alt="Youtube" /><span style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0;"><a style="color: #cccccc;" href="https://www.google.co.uk/" title="Youtube" >Watch us on Youtube</a></span>    
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
```

The "vertical-align: middle;" style does not work in Outlook 2007/2010 and the text next to the image is appearing below the image. Does anyone know of a work around to get the text to align to the middle of the image? It works fine in other email clients. It is just Outlook that is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

i never success to use "vertical-align" statement in Outlook. 
I made table for hack this but it not really easy

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#666f87" style="background: #666f87;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" >
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3">
            <font style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0;">
                <strong>Social Media:</strong>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <img style="border:0; display: inline-block;" src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
        </td>
        <td width="5" />
        <td align="left">
            <span style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0;">
                <a style="color: #cccccc;" href="#" title="Facebook" >
                Become a fan on Facebook
              </a>
        </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3" height="5" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
             <img style="border:0; display: inline-block;" src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
        </td>
        <td width="5" />
        <td align="left">
            <span style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0;">
                <a style="color: #cccccc;" href="#" title="Twitterk" >
                    Follow us on Twitter
                </a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3" height="5" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
             <img style="border:0; display: inline-block;" src="youtube.png" alt="Youtube" />
        </td>
        <td width="5" />
        <td align="left">
            <span style="color: #cccccc; font-size: 11px; font-family: arial; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0;">
                <a style="color: #cccccc;" href="https://www.google.co.uk/" title="Youtube" >
                   Watch us on Youtube
                </a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing?